# Google Spreadsheets replace cell range with data minus empty cells

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am making a script allows you to consolidate a todo list after finished items are erased. 
I am getting a range, using an if statement to push all non-zero cell values from the specified range to an array, clearing the cell range and then re-pasting the new array (minus the cells with no data) back into the same range.  Here is my code: (thanks mogsdad!)

```
function onOpen()
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Consolidate To-Do list', functionName: 'consolidatetodolist_'}
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('LB functions', menuItems);
};


function consolidatetodolist_()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:A19");
  var rangeValues = range.getValues();
  var todosArray = new Array(); 
  for (var i = 0 ; i < rangeValues.length ; i++ ) { 
      var row = rangeValues[i];
      var cell = row [0];
      if (null !== cell && "" !== cell)  {
      todosArray.push(row);
      };
  };

  Logger.log(todosArray);
  range.clearContent();
  range.offset(0,0,todosArray.length).setValues(todosArray);    

    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your edit trigger should not be manipulating the menu. You should have an `onOpen` trigger do that. If you want the consolidation to be automatic, then you could drive THAT from your onEdit.

In your `consolidatetodolist_()` function, you've got a handful of errors regarding value assignment, Javascript fundamentals.

- Using the SpreadsheetApp services to get the value of `valueInstance` isn't necessary. You've already got it, in  `rangeValues[i][0]`. Note the two indexes; the data stored in rangeValues is a two-dimensional array, even though your range was one column. The first index is *rows*, the second is *columns*. (Opposite order from A1Notation.)
- `if ( range.getLength(valueInstance) !== 0 )` should crash, because `range` is an instance of `Class Range` which has no `getLength()` method. What you intend to check is whether the current cell is blank. Since spreadsheet data can be of three javascript types (String, Number, Date), you need a comparison that can cope with any of them, as well as an empty cell which is `null`. Try `if (null !== cell && "" !== cell)...`
- When you get to `setValues`, you will need to supply a two-dimensional array that is the same dimensions as `range`. First, you need to ensure `todosArray` is an array of arrays (array of rows, where a row is an array of cells). Easiest way to do that here is to use `var row = rangeValues[i]; var cell = row[0];`, then later `todosArray.push(row);`. Since you are clearing the original range first, you could then define a new range relative to it using `offset(0,0,todosArray.length).setValues(todosArray)`.

Other nitpicking:

- You've got the idea of using meaningful variable names, good. But instead of `valueInstance`, `cell` would make this code clearer.
- Use of "magic numbers" should be avoided, because it makes it harder to understand, maintain, and reuse code. Instead of `i < 18`, for example, you could use `i < rangeValues .length`. That way, if you modified the size of the range you're consolidating, the for loop would adapt without change.
- Declaring `var i` outside of the for loop. No error with what you've done (although a declaration with no value assigned is bad), and it makes no difference to the machine, but for humans it's clearer to define `i` in the for loop, unless you need to use it outside of the loop. `for (var i = 0; ...`

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH for your help.  Here's the final code, following all of your advice. and it works.

Comment: I tried to post it, but it makes the comment too long.  I'll post it as an answer.